# Redirection after gmail logout is showing "Redirect notice" instead of application page

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-signin

My application is using **Google sign-in** but signout of which is not working properly. It is redirecting the user to an intermediate page with title **"Redirect Notice"**. This is happening since last few weeks.

Application logout URL:

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue=http://example.com
```

I am trying to redirect the user back to my application (with URL: http://example.com)

but it is showing an intermediate page:

[image: Redirect Notice page]

How can I remove this intermediate page and redirect user back to http://example.com?